# Running Simple Hadoop Programs On Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, libraries

I am pretty new to hadoop & ubuntu so please bear with me. I find it very inconvenient to compile my hadoop .java files from command line. So I have created an eclipse project & imported all the hadoop libraries so that the eclipse does not throw any reference errors. And it does not. However when I run the files as a standalone java application I get the following error

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

I am running on ubuntu and I have researched this problem elsewhere on web. I do not expect to see this error since the only difference is that I am running it within eclipse and not from command line. Where I am going wrong. Is there a specific way in which I need to add hadoop dependencies to my hello world hadoop projects? Will a simple buildpath configuration and importing of the necessary libraries not suffice? Appreciate all your responses.

Answer (score 1):

you can try right-clicking the Project, ->Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Go to your src folder, point to "Native Library", then edit the location to the location of your hadoop native library folder (normally: ~/hadoop-x.x.x/lib/native/"folder-depending-on-your-system")

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning and not an error which tells you that there is some problem in loading the native libraries which Hadoop makes use of. It should not have any negative impact on your job's output though. Remember Hadoop has native implementations of certain components for performance reasons and for non-availability of Java implementations. On the *nix platforms the library is named **libhadoop.so**. Using Eclipse doesn't make any difference the way Hadoop works. It's just that your Eclipse is unable to load the native libraries due to some reasons.

One possible reason might be that there is some problem with your **java.library.path**. You can configure Eclipse to load the proper libraries by configuring the **build path** as per your environment. To know more about Hadoop's native libraries, and how to build and use them you can visit this **[link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html)**.